# How to restart application on button click in ios?

Tags: ios

Ones my application finishes executing, I need to restart it in order to be able to reuse it again.

I am curious if there is a way I could add an action Listener to a "RESTART" button that would close and reopen my application?

Comment: No way. In case of Storyboard application you may use this method  UIViewController* initialScene = [_initalStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = initialScene;

Comment: only way would be to advise the user via alert view or other way to quit the app and launch again.

Comment: As a not possible for call direct didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method?

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. iOS doesn't provide API for this functionality. You may have luck with a jailbroken device.

Anyways, you have bigger problems if your app needs to restart to be usable.

Comment: sir , As a not possible for call direct didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question.

Comment: code of call delegate method for didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: Hindi mein hi bol do…

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in iOS. Because there is no functionality to restart the application on button click.

Answer (score 0):

You should not force the user to restart the app, even automatic shut-down and restart. The user will be annoyed and not use your app ever.

Also this is against the guidelines.

Comment: The user is asking how to restart an app, not the device.

Comment: @MatthewVosburgh: Thanks for bringing this *typo* :p